# Is there any built in call recording tool in windows phone?

Tags: 8.1, calls

I have found plenty app in windows app store for recording calls, but i am wondering if there is a built in call recording tool in windows phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. There are no 3rd party apps, either, since the OS blocks any other apps from using the mic while you are in a phone call.

EDIT: For reference, call recording functionality has been built into Windows 10 Mobile.